# Switch case doesen't change

Tags: c#, networking, .net-core, server, client

[Github project repository link](https://github.com/Capmare/Cloud-Server-and-Client)

> this is the server

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
            IPAddress hostname = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.253");
            Int32 port = 9999;
            TcpListener server = null;
            TcpClient client = null;
            string data = null;
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            server = new TcpListener(hostname, port);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("server has started ");
            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("server accepts clients now");
            NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine("server started data stream");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            dataStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
            string cleanData = data.Replace("\0", "");
            Console.WriteLine(cleanData);
            do
            {
                try
                {
```

> here is the problem

```
                    switch (cleanData)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            List<string> dir = new List<string>();
                            string message = $"Current path is: {path}";
                            dir.Add(message);
                            bf.Serialize(dataStream, dir);
                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                        case "2":
                            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                            foreach (var file in files)
                            {
                                filesList.Add(file);

                            }

                            bf.Serialize(dataStream, filesList);
                            filesList.Clear();
                            filesList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("waiting for input");

                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                    }
```

```
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        } while (true);

    }
```

> this is the client

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string hostname = "192.168.0.253";
        int port = 9999;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.Connect(hostname, port);
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Connected to the main server");
        }


        private void GetList()
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            serverStream = client.GetStream();
            int buff = 0;
            byte[] instream = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buff = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
            List<string> data = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(serverStream);
            //string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream);
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);

            }
            serverStream.Flush();
            return;


        }

        private void getData()
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            serverStream = client.GetStream();
            int buff = 0;
            byte[] instream = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buff = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
            List<string> data = (List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(serverStream);
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }

            serverStream.Flush();
            return;
        }

        private void ShowItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "2";
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
            dataStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            GetList();
            return;
        }

        private void ReloadItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
            string message = "2";
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
            dataStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            GetList();
            return;

        }

        private void DownloadItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> itemsToDownload = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                itemsToDownload.Add(item as string);
            }
            return;
        }

        private void ShowDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string message = "1";
            byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
            dataStream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            getData();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to make this data storage server with client to be able to download and store all my data in one single device, something like my own cloud, but i got a problem that i m not able to resolve and that is with the switch statement in the server, it seems that it gets stuck at the switch, if i delete the do loop it just ends the program.
I also added the client side and the github repository if there is any need to run the program.

> The server is made in .net-core and the client in windows form app both on visual studio 2019

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've included a *lot* of code here - too much to expect folks to read through. It would really help if you'd reduce this to a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem. I strongly suspect that while doing so, you'll find the problem - but if you don't, you'll have a much better reproduction for us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

where the do loop is i needed to add the variable cleadata to refresh the value of the switch every time after the switch breaks

```
            do
            {
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                    string cleanData = data.Replace("\0", ""); 
                    Console.WriteLine(cleanData); 
                try
                {

                    switch (cleanData)
                    {
                        case "1":
                            List<string> dir = new List<string>();
                            string message = $"Current path is: {path}";
                            dir.Add(message);
                            bf.Serialize(dataStream, dir);
                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                        case "2":
                            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                            foreach (var file in files)
                            {
                                filesList.Add(file);

                            }

                            bf.Serialize(dataStream, filesList);
                            filesList.Clear();
                            filesList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("waiting for input");

                            dataStream.Flush();

                            break;
                    }

            }
```